# \sqrt[x]{y} Breaks With unicode-math

Tags: xetex, unicode-math

I’m having trouble with XeLaTeX (0.9998) and `unicode-math` (0.7a). If I use `\setmathfont` more than twice, the `\sqrt` command breaks when a superscript is specified.

```
\documentclass{minmal}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\setmathfont[range=\mathup/{num,latin,Latin}]{Linux Libertine O}
\setmathfont[range=\mathup/{greek,Greek}]{Symbola}
\begin{document}
\[ \sqrt[5]{2} \]
\end{document}
```

If I typeset this code, XeLaTeX will produce the following error

```
Font \l_tmpb_font has only 8 fontdimen parameters.
```

If I remove the superscript from `\sqrt` or remove the last `\setmathfont` command, the document compiles correctly. I’ve tested this code with several OTF files, and they all produced the same result. (I know the resulting superscript is improperly positioned, but I can work on this once I know the document can be typeset.)

[I filed a bug for this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/issues/245) because I believe it’s a problem with the package, but I should have checked here before doing so, and I will gladly close the bug if I find I was doing something stupid.

Comment: You forgot to activate the mathmode `$\sqrt[5]{2}$`.

Comment: I have no issues with the demo if I tidy it up (for example, use font file names rather than names, use math fonts in all cases, _etc._).

Comment: @Joseph: But it should be possible to use non-math-fonts for special symbols. For me `\setmathfont[range=\mathrm]{Arial}` breaks too  – but only if I use the optional argument of `\sqrt`: `$\sqrt[5]{2}$`.

Comment: Agh! I apologize, but my original post should have included `\[ \]` around the `\sqrt` command. The error occurs when math mode is invoked; my original example obviously fails for other reasons.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Exactly.The radical and the vinculum for the square root should come from Latin Modern Math, and the superscript should come from Linux Libertine O since I only defined it for numbers and Latin characters. This is why I suspect the culprit is the package itself, since the problem only occurs if a second `\setmathfont` is defined for a range.

Comment: XeTeX and math typesetting are not good friends: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/281549/why-is-the-fraction-off-the-math-axis-in-xetex

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tracing through the code, the issue is that `unicode-math` redefines `\r@@t`, which is used by LaTeX when it typesets a root with an index.  The redefinition is different for LuaTeX and XeTeX, so you only see the issue with XeTeX. In that case, it is

```
\cs_set_nopar:Npn \r@@t #1 #2 {
  \hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box {
    \c_math_toggle_token
    \m@th
    #1
    \sqrtsign { #2 }
    \c_math_toggle_token
  }
  \um_mathstyle_scale:Nnn #1 { \kern } {
    \fontdimen 63 \l_um_font
  }
  \box_move_up:nn {
    (\box_ht:N \l_tmpa_box - \box_dp:N \l_tmpa_box)
    * \number \fontdimen 65 \l_um_font / 100
  } {
    \box_use:N \rootbox
  }
  \um_mathstyle_scale:Nnn #1 { \kern } {
    \fontdimen 64 \l_um_font
  }
  \box_use_drop:N \l_tmpa_box
}
```

The key here is the `\fontdimen` business: these are 'high number' font dimensions which are not available in traditional TeX. As such, these are not defined for text fonts: they are only available for 'proper' Unicode math fonts. You therefore see the error only if you set up some symbols to be taken from a text font.

Comment: Thank you! I only know enough LaTeX3 to be dangerous, so digging through the style definition proved useless to me.

Comment: @AstroPig7 At present, the code here is a bit of a mishmash, to be honest, so it's more a question of knowing what might be up (the error immediately suggested something to me).

Comment: Wait, what: `\fontdimen 64`? Do you know where could I find more information about those higher fontdimens?

Comment: @morbusg: they are documented at the end of `unicode-math` manual.

Answer (score 8):

Obviously `unicode-math` maps the last font set with `\setmathfont` to `\l_um_font` and then uses it in `\r@@t` to get the `\fontdimen` values. So you could try as a workaround to remap `\l_um_font` to your "main" math font:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\setmathfont[range=\mathbb]{Arial}
\setmathfont[range=\int]{Latin Modern Math}
\begin{document}
\[ \sqrt[5]{2} \mathbb{ABC} \]
\end{document}
```

I'm not quite sure what `unicode-math` should do in this situation, but probably `\r@@t` should use the font of the actual radical symbol. (And it should sort out the redefinitions of `\r@@t`. at line 2098 is looks as if it would redefine only when `amsmath` is not loaded but later on it does it anyway. Very confusing ;-).)

Comment: Yes, I found the AMS stuff rather odd, and like you I'm not sure quite what is 'right' here.

Comment: I added your suggestion to my test document and it worked like a charm. I’m currently adding all of the other symbols and alphabets I need to see if anything else breaks.