# unicode-math + TeX Gyre Termes Math without \bigstar?

Tags: math-mode, unicode-math, tex-gyre-math

When I use TeX Gyre Termes Math with `unicode-mat`h like in the example I can't get the `\bigstar` symbol. It seems that the font does not have a bigstar at U-2605. Is there a way to re-define the `\bigstar` command to deliver a scaled version of the `\star` command to fit the math sizes? BTW, `\ast` is a lot bigger than `\star`; I wouldn't have to bother about `\bigstar` if `\star` were of the same size as `\ast`.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Numbers=OldStyle, Ligatures=TeX]{TeX Gyre Termes}
\usepackage[math-style=ISO]{unicode-math}%
\setmathfont[Numbers=Lining]{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    (\mathbb{Z}(p))^\star \star \qquad 
    \left(\mathbb{Z}(p)\right)^{\bigstar} \bigstar\qquad
    (\mathbb{Z}(p))^\ast \ast
\end{equation}
    ---$\symbol{"2605}$\symbol{"2605}---
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The glyph corresponding to U+2605 is not available in TeX Gyre Termes (text and math). You can use the glyph from another font:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[math-style=ISO]{unicode-math}

\setmainfont[Numbers=OldStyle, Ligatures=TeX]{TeX Gyre Termes}

\setmathfont[Numbers=Lining]{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
\setmathfont[range=\bigstar]{XITS Math}
\setmathfont[range=\int]{TeX Gyre Termes Math} % just to get parameters from this font

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
(\mathbb{Z}(p))^\star \star \qquad
\mathbb{Z}(p))^{\bigstar} \bigstar\qquad
(\mathbb{Z}(p))^\ast \ast
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that `Numbers=Lining` for TeX Gyre Termes Math is meaningless. Also, using oldstyle figures with Times New Roman (or any lookalike thereof) is an anachronism.

Note also that `\bigstar` is classified as a math ordinary symbol, so you need `\mathbin{\bigstar}` when you want it to act as a binary operation symbol.

Comment: that's it. That way I can replace the `\star` with one of `\ast` size. (XIT's bigstar looks too big as a superscript.) I'm not using a Times-like font in my project. While we're at it: Can I replace the numerals with those from another font, too?

Comment: @Blackface You'd still have the problem of letters in math mode that would be different.

Comment: I made the minimal example just for the \star question. I actually have some lines like `\setmathfont[range=\mathup/{latin,Latin,num},Numbers=Lining]{Calluna}` between the `range={\star,\bigstar}` and the `range=\int`. I found out about the `num` after I posted my last comment.

Comment: The `\setmathfont[range=\int]{TeX Gyre Termes Math}` line should be last to circumvent a problem with `unicode-math`, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/67058/4427 Your case of using `Calluna` is exactly the one addressed by the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You may enlarge the original star with help of the `relsize` package. The height is not absolutely identical like this, but the approach is quite easy and you are using the same font for both symbols.

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Numbers=OldStyle, Ligatures=TeX]{texgyretermes-regular.otf}
\usepackage[math-style=ISO]{unicode-math}%
\setmathfont{texgyretermes-math.otf}
\usepackage{relsize}
\newcommand{\STAR}{\mathlarger{\mathlarger{\star}}}

\begin{document}        
$\STAR\star\ast$

\newdimen\astheight
\setbox0=\hbox{$\ast$}
\astheight=\ht0 \advance\astheight by \dp0
The height of the $\ast$ symbol is: \the\astheight

\newdimen\STARheight
\setbox0=\hbox{$\STAR$}
\STARheight=\ht0 \advance\STARheight by \dp0
The height of the $\STAR$ symbol is: \the\STARheight

$
(\mathbb{Z}(p))^\star \star \qquad
\mathbb{Z}(p))^{\STAR} \STAR \qquad
(\mathbb{Z}(p))^\ast \ast
$
\end{document}
```

[image]