# Non-math fonts with unicode-math kill \widetilde and \widehat

Tags: unicode-math

I suspect this might be a bug in `unicode-math`, but you never know. It appears that loading any non-math font for any purpose at all breaks `\widehat` and `\widetilde`. Consider, for instance, the MWE below where I load XITS Math as my math font, but try some other fonts for `\mathbfup`. That should have absolutely no effect for what happens to my math except when using bold upright math. However, even though the font does not change for the math I type, the `\widetilde`and `\widehat` become either normal `\tilde` and `\hat`... or disappear completely, depending on the font I load.

**Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong somewhere?**

(As the MWE suggests, I am compiling using LuaLaTeX.)

```
% !TeX program=luatex

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmathfont{XITS Math}

\begin{document}

$\widetilde X\widehat X$

\setmathfont[range=\mathbfup]{Minion Pro Bold}

$\widetilde X\widehat X$

\setmathfont[range=\mathbfup]{Linux Libertine O Bold}

$\widetilde X\widehat X$

\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT:** Compiling using XeLaTeX, I get the following instead. This makes me even more confident that there is a bug somewhere.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The workaround suggested by Ulrike Fischer in her answer to [\sqrt[x]{y} Breaks With unicode-math](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66966/sqrtxy-breaks-with-unicode-math) works also in this case:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmathfont{XITS Math}
\setmathfont[range=\mathbfup]{Linux Libertine O Bold}
\setmathfont[range=\int]{XITS Math}

\begin{document}

$\widetilde X\widehat X\mathbf{X}$

\end{document}
```

Note that you shouldn't be changing math font inside the document. The problem is that `unicode-math` gets some values for math typesetting from the *last* loaded math font. Since Linux Libertine isn't a math font, it doesn't have some necessary parameters.

[image]

Note that the last glyph is from Linux Libertine.

Comment: I guess this is the cleaner solution, since it directly addresses the cause of the issue. Accepted. Isn't it kind of a bug that the last loaded font determines how fractions and accents look? Shouldn't that come from the main math font?

Comment: do you think it would cause problems to just put the line `\setmathfont{XITS Math}` last, after all other `\setmathfont`s?

Comment: @Gaussler I prefer not doing it, just for consistency, but you can experiment.

Answer (score 4):

The accent is not there as warned in the log

```
Missing character: There is no ̃ (U+0303) in font "MinionProBold:mode=base;scri
pt=latn;language=DFLT;"!
```

Why `\widetilde` is being redefined to use the new `\symnum_fam1`
allocated to the bold minion font, I'm not sure, but you can define it back again:

```
% !TeX program=luatex

\documentclass{article}

\show\widetilde

\usepackage{unicode-math}


\setmathfont{XITS Math}

\begin{document}
\show\widetilde
\show\symoperators
$\widetilde X\widehat X$

\let\oldwidetilde\widetilde
\let\oldwidehat\widehat
\setmathfont[range=\mathbfup]{Minion Pro Bold}
\let\widetilde\oldwidetilde
\let\widehat\oldwidehat

$\widetilde X\widehat X$

\setmathfont[range=\mathbfup]{Linux Libertine O Bold}

$\widetilde X\widehat X$

\end{document}
```

I don't think unicode-math really claims to support non math fonts in this way, so it's not clearly a bug, but may be worth raising on the unicode-math issue tracker anyway.

Comment: In order for the interface to work logically, I think that changing what happens in `\mathbfup` should have no effect on what happens to the rest of the math. Particularly so when replacing `range=\mathbfup` by `range=\mathbfup/{latin,Latin,greek,Greek}`; however, it also happens in that case.